# I have an excel from which I am pulling values, and I need to separate those values from commas

Tags: python, arrays, excel, split, assign

From excel I am pulling the following array:

```
g = ['', '', '', '', '', '234,1111,550', '', '', '', '', '']
```

How do I tell python to get that '234,1111,550' out of that array and assign it each of those three numbers to an individual letter. So, a = 234, b = 1111, and c = 550. Basically, I want to split those three. Also, the array may have two numbers like that instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to get a list of splitted items:

```
>>> [item.split(',') for item in g if item]
[['234', '1111', '550']]
>>>
```

And if you just want the first occurrence you can use a generator expression within `next()` function:

```
>>> 
>>> next((item.split(',') for item in g if item), None)
['234', '1111', '550']
```

If you want to assign the items to variables you need to be aware of the number of items, then you can just do:

```
a, b, c = ['234', '1111', '550']
```

Comment: Okay. But, then I need to assign those values to a,b,c. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you already have a list in python with values of '' and other values of Strings which are separated by a comma.
Therefore, you may want to iterate over the list and whenever you reach a string you would split it:

```
g = ['', '', '', '', '', '234,1111,550', '', '', '', '', '']
results = []
for element in g:
     if element != '':
          results.extend(element.split(","))
print(results)
```

EDIT: As for your comments this is the code so that it will adjust your needs.
Assuming results has 3 elements, then you can save them as float by casting with list comprehension:

```
a,b,c = [float(x) for x in results]
```

Comment: Same question I asked Kasramvd, how to assign those values to a,b,c

Comment: say results list has 3 elements, then do:  a,b,c = results

Comment: They are coming out as strings. I want them to be float. I can't do any calculations because of that.

Comment: Say a has the string value, Cast it to float by num=float(a)

Comment: @Bob H. I edited the answer for your needs, use what's more comfortable to you

Comment: @BobH. if that was helpful to you, consider accepting it as an answer.